# Cakephp rerouting

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, routes

Hi I d'like to be able to rewrite my url. I have this format of url:

```
localhost/example/urlrewriting/Links/view/1
```

and I want to change this url to

```
http://localhost/example/urlrewriting/tt/my-link-1
```

In my Routes.php I have done this:

```
    Router::connect('tt/:slug-:id',
    array('controller' =>'links', 'action' => 'test'),
    array('pass' => array('slug', 'id'), 'slug' => '[a-z0-9\-]+', 'id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

and in my controller I have this

```
    public function test($param1, $param2){
    debug($this->request->params);
}
```

I've always find this answer:

```
TtController could not be found.
```

cakephp 2.4.1

Answer (score 2):

Please add `/` before the connect params like:-

```
Router::connect('/tt/:slug-:id',
array('controller' =>'links', 'action' => 'test'),
array('pass' => array('slug', 'id'), 'slug' => '[a-z0-9\-]+', 'id' => '[0-9]+'));
```